# How to add to an existing dataTransfer.files object with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a drag and drop file upload zone. When I upload multiple files at a time it works but I need it to be able to support uploading in multiple stages. I know that the issue below is that I am setting files each time, but I can't figure out the right way to get more files added to dFiles each time the method is called

```
    var dFiles;
    //var dFiles = []
    var holder = document.getElementById('holder');
    holder.ondrop = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dFiles = (e.dataTransfer.files);
        //dFiles.push(e.dataTransfer.files);
   }
```

I tried initilaizing dfiles as an empty array and adding the files (commented out above). Later this created a data type mismatch error when I was reading the file data

```
for (var i = 0; i < dFiles.length; i++) {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataUrl(dFiles[i]); //error
}
```

Comment: Why not create an array containing the different dFiles ? (a different dFile variable being created at each drop)
So you would not try to concat different dFiles together.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you should use `dFiles.concat` and not `dFiles.push` as dFiles is already an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`e.dataTransfer.files` is a [list of files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).

You will have to add each file separately to `dFiles`:

```
var files = e.dataTransfer.files;

for (var i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; i++) {
    dFiles.push(files[i]);
}
```

Or the ES6 way:

```
dFiles.push(...e.dataTransfer.files);
```

Comment: Why not concat ?

Comment: @Sylvain (At least for Chrome/Webkit) step [7b](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.concat) in the specification seems to return `false` because `.concat()` adds the `FileList` as an object and not as separate files.

Comment: This results in `Uncaught TypeError: inputFileElement.files.push is not a function`, the MDN doesn't describe a push method either.

Comment: @MarcWittke I'm not quite sure what you're talking about because my answer doesn't try to change the read-only `FileList` property of the file input element O.o `dFiles` is an array (check the question)

Comment: @Andreas, oh, you're right. The title is very misleading, because @cooper actually wants to add something to an array, not to a `FileList` object