# request getting the last file in form has inputs filled by datatransfer, laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms, data-transfer, filelist

first of all, I don't know if it's legal to do this, but please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70896448/why-i-get-only-the-last-uploaded-file-in-the-form-laravel) to understand me better.

as you read in the question, I have trouble pushing new files into an input, I knew that I get only the last file because of **pushing** the files into input's file list. so I changed pushing from this: (*which was working, but only on last input in the form*)

```
function inputImage(quode, f){
    let list = new DataTransfer();
    list.items.add(f);
    let img = list.files;

    document.querySelector("#imageUploader_"+quode).files = img;
}
```

to this:

```
function inputImage(quode, f){
   document.querySelector("#imageUploader_"+quode).files.push(f);
}
```

but I get this error

> `document.querySelector(...).files.push` is not a function

I get it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164514/18001301)

I've also tried this

```
function inputImage(quode, f){
    document.querySelector("#imageUploader_"+quode).files.add(f);
}
```

but I get this

> TypeError: `document.querySelector(...).files.add` is not a function

the file object looks like (from the console):

```
File {
  lastModified: 1642515255138
  lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 18 2022 17:14:15 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
  name: "[(33),12,2314,100,45].jpeg"
  size: 8115
  type: "image/jpeg"
  webkitRelativePath: ""
  [[Prototype]]: File
}
```

the file list :

```
FileList {length: 0[[Prototype]]: FileList}
```

[image]

**EDIT**:
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696572/uncaught-typeerror-data-push-is-not-a-function) it may help

and this is some documentation:

1. [Mozilla datatransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)
2. [Mozilla FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason wasn't related to datatransfer even nor related to JS. the problem that I wasn't managing the request array perfectly, so I only get the last input's file, so I changed the request from this

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $gen = ['_token','examHash','name','duration','bornline','deadline','note','hardness','vip','examType','published'];
        $questions = $request->except($gen);//questions
        $data = [];
        $count = 0;
        foreach($questions as $k => $i){
            if(str_starts_with($k, 'ex_')){
                $quode= '';
                $ex = '';
                $type = '';
                $quode = str_replace("ex_", "", $k);
                $ex = $i;
                $type = $questions['questionType_'.$quode];
                $count += 1;
            }
            $data += [$quode => []];
            if(str_ends_with($k, $quode)){
                // check if the $k is unnecessary element and skip it, add only needed data to $data array
                if((($type == "option" && (!str_starts_with($k, "label") && !str_starts_with($k, "single") && !str_starts_with($k, "choice"))) || ($type == "label" && (!str_starts_with($k, "option") && !str_starts_with($k, "single"))) || ($type == "single" && (!str_starts_with($k, "label") && !str_starts_with($k, "option") && !str_starts_with($k, "choice"))))){
                    $data[$quode]['sort'] = $count;
                    $data[$quode] += [str_replace("_".$quode, "", $k) => $i];
                }
                if(str_starts_with($k, "image")){
                    $questions['image_'.$quode]->storeAs('ques', $quode.$ex);
                }
            }
        }
        $data = array_merge(request()->only($gen), $data);
        dd($data);
    }
```

to this

```
foreach($questions as $k => $i){
    if(str_starts_with($k, 'ex_')){
        $quode= '';
        $ex = '';
        $type = '';
        $image= [''];
        $quode = str_replace("ex_", "", $k);
        $ex = $i;
        $type = $questions['questionType_'.$quode];
        $image = $questions['image_'.$quode];
        $count += 1;
    }
    $data += [$quode => []];
    if(str_ends_with($k, $quode)){
        // check if the $k is unnecessary element and skip it, add only needed data to $data array
        if((($type == "option" && (!str_starts_with($k, "label") && !str_starts_with($k, "single") && !str_starts_with($k, "choice"))) || ($type == "label" && (!str_starts_with($k, "option") && !str_starts_with($k, "single"))) || ($type == "single" && (!str_starts_with($k, "label") && !str_starts_with($k, "option") && !str_starts_with($k, "choice"))))){
            $data[$quode]['sort'] = $count;
            $data[$quode] += [str_replace("_".$quode, "", $k) => $i];
            $data[$quode]['image'] = $image;
            $data[$quode]['image']->storeAs('ques', $quode.$ex);
        }
    }
}
```